# how we add more symbol file in gdb

Tags: gdb

I have more than 10 symbol files to add at runtime in gdb

```
add-symbol-file build/i386//fat 0x80a211dc
add-symbol-file build/i386/fs/cd9660/cd9660 0x00000ac0
add-symbol-file build/i386/fs/ntfs/ntfs 0x00001518
```

---

Adding all files one by one in gdb is very time consuming job & takes more time. Does gdb have only one command to add all files at proper place?
I used gdb command

```
set debug-file-directory
```

but it does not work, so plz help

Comment: How about putting it in ~/.gdbinit?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in command to do what you want.

However, you can automate gdb using either the built-in command language (the "CLI") or using Python.  I don't know how you find those addresses, but the idea would be to automate that with a script.

For the CLI this automation could perhaps be done via the `shell` command, writing a sequence of `add-symbol-file` commands to a file, which you'd then `source`.

For Python you can simply write a program that eventually uses `gdb.execute` to evaluate the `add-symbol-file` commands you need.